# cannot convert type to bool

Tags: c#

```
    public static void PathFinder (Client C, Path Distance)
    {
    if (C.Recording)
    {

      if(Distance to C.Path[C.PathIndex] < 7); 
      {
      if(C.PathIndex + 1< C.Path.Count)
      {
         C.PathIndex++; 
      }
      else
      {
         C.Recording = true;
         C.Path = new List<Coord>();
         C.PathIndex = 0;
         C.Path.Add(new Point(C.X, C.Y));
         C.Path = C.Path.Reverse();
         C.PathIndex = 1;
      }
         Coord To = Calculations.PullWeights(MakeCoord(C.X, C.Y), C.Path[C.PathIndex]);
      } 
    }
}
```

I am getting several errors, but I`m not sure how to fix the problem. I have looked at solutions but am still a little clueless >.<

Comment: Where are the errors happening?  What errors are they?

Comment: Unless you include useful information like what errors you're getting, and what line they're happening on - we're not going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
if(Distance to C.Path[C.PathIndex] < 7);
```

Firstly `Distance to C.Path[C.PathIndex]` is not a valid expression.  You need to replace it with an expression that does calculate the distance.

Secondly the semi-colon at the end of the line must not be there.  You are literally saying `if (x) doNothing();`

Comment: >.< Now I`m more lost than ever lol. Yeah wasn`t to sure about the semi-colon as I have had a look around the net for an answer but I am clueless as to what to put instead :(

Comment: Just remove the semi-colon, your existing `{}` brackets will then be in the right place.

Comment: public static void Pathfinder (Client C, PathFinder Distance)
            {
            if (!C.Recording)
            {
                
              if (Distance to C.Path [C.PathIndex] < 7) 
            {
              if(C.PathIndex + 1< C.Path.Count)
                {
                 C.PathIndex++; 
              }
              else

Comment: public static int Distance(ushort X, ushort Y, ushort ToX, ushort ToY)
        {
            int XDist = Math.Abs(X - ToX);
            int YDist = Math.Abs(Y - ToY);
            if (XDist > YDist)
                return XDist;
            else
                return YDist;
        }

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the error happens here:

```
if(Distance to C.Path[C.PathIndex] < 7);
```

This doesn't look like a valid C# expression, and that's what gives you the conversion error

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly :) But what or how would I replace it >.<

Answer (score 0):

1. `if (C.Recording)` - if `Recording` is not a `bool` Property, then this won't work
2. `if(Distance to C.Path[C.PathIndex] < 7);` this isn't legal C#, and loose the trailing semicolon

Update:

I'm not sure if `(!C.Recording)` will work either. I don't know what the type of Recording is. If it's a bool, then it's all fine, but if not, then you need to create a boolean expression.

For instance, if `Recording` is a `string` type, then you'll need to do

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(C.Recording)) { ... }
```

Comment: public bool Recording = false;